# How do I close colorbox iframe with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I need to close the colorbox iframe that overlays the website with an onclick event. I have seen the code as `parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false;`, but it doesn't work for me when I use it like this: `<a onclick="parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false;">close</a>`. I think that it is because I am not using a standard colorbox script to call the iframe. I modified it so that I can get height and width from the html anchor tag:

MY COLORBOX SCRIPT:

```
$.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("a[rel='colorbox']").each(function(){
                    var getWidth = parseInt($(this).attr('width'))
                    var getHeight = parseInt($(this).attr('height'))
                    var getScroll = parseInt($(this).attr('scrolling'))
                    if(getScroll == 'yes') { var frameScroll = 'true'; }
                    if(!getWidth) { var getWidth = '720'; }
                    if(!getHeight) { var getHeight = '480'; }

                    $(this).colorbox({innerWidth:getWidth, innerHeight:getHeight, scrolling:frameScroll, iframe:true, rel:"nofollow", transition:"elastic"});
            });
    });
```

What do I need to use to close this iframe onclick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false;
```

Use this:

```
parent.jQuery.colorbox.close(); return false;
```

You are calling noConflict, which divorces jQuery from the $ alias. Therefor your iframe is not going to be able to access jQuery through that $ alias.

Comment: Perfect! I knew that it had something to do with the way that I was calling it!

Answer (score 0):

you can either do `<a onclick="$.colorbox.close(); return false;">close</a>` or you can do something like `$("#idOfCloseLink").click( function() { $.colorbox.close() });`

Comment: yes, I just reread the post and saw the noConflict declaration. Glad you got it working.